# Showing PDF.js page from JavaFX in WebView

Tags: javafx, webview, pdf.js

Loading document from WebEngine by m_engine.load(".../web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf"); works well.

In the given container PDF.js appears to work well whatever I try the document is rendered properly and I can navigate.

Event is dispatched to WeEngine properly as:

```
        m_engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        m_engine.executeScript("PDFViewerApplication.page=12;");
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, whis executeScript does not work. Quietly, i.e. no exceptions.

If I start with no pdf document and in ChangeListener do: 
...m_engine.executeScript("PDFViewerApplication.open('compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf')");
... the document is loaded properly, meaning that the PDFViewerApplication object is ok.

I didn't manage to find PDFViewerApplication documentation

Comment: Is it your real goal to show PDF documents in WebView or do you just try to use a WebView to show PDFs in JavaFX?

Comment: I need to show PDFs in JavaFX in an eLearning designer application - i.e. need some meta-data/navigational control over docs from JavaFX

Comment: I don't know if this is a case, but sometimes there is an Exception property that you have to listen to in order to see exceptions.

Comment: Exceptions work well. Each time I tried impossible I got an exception. I did not get an exception in the code example because because executeScript call is ok. It just doesn't do the work when called from inside ChangeListener.

Answer (score 1):

If your real goal is just to be able to view PDFs inside of a JavaFX applications, then you might want to have a look here: [PDFViewer](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/GemsFX)
Internally it uses Apache PDFBox which is very powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

As 'open' method of PDFViewerApplication works well from inside ChangeListener this is how doc can be positioned at a desired page initially:

PDF.js code is initialised first, in our JavaFX code, by not specifying the document we need to render. E.g.:

```
m_engine.load("http://localhost/Q/modules/viewers/pdf/web/viewer.html");
```

And the following will load the document and position it at the desired page:

```
        m_engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        m_engine.executeScript("PDFViewerApplication.initialBookmark='page=5';PDFViewerApplication.open('compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf');");
                    }
                }
            });
```